# is there any way to make on change event work when we click on some thing else using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

after so many research i have achieved this
we have 3 images and 3 options when i select 1st image first option from select is being selected ,
The remaining thing is onchange event on select is not working how can i achieve that ?
this is the code i have tried this to trigger on change event but no luck

```
    $('.product-medias .swiper-slide').each(function(item, index){
    
    $(this).click(function(){
        console.log('clicked')
        
        var secondIndexSelect = $(this).attr('data-media-index');
        var parsedIndex = parseInt(secondIndexSelect, 10)
        $("select#SingleOptionSelector-0 option").eq(`${parsedIndex}`).prop('selected', true).trigger('change'); // trigger "change" and "focus" i have tried both
        $('.product-single__media-s .product-single__media').removeClass('product-single__media--selected');
        $(`.product-single__media-s .product-single__media:nth-child(${parsedIndex + 1})`).addClass('product-single__media--selected');
    })
})
```

right now in my code when i select index 1 image the first option is selected but on change event is not working . is there any way to bind it ?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `.each()`. Methods like `.click()` automatically loop over all the selected elements.

Comment: Your code isn't triggering on change, it's triggering on click. Use `.change()` to handle the change event.

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind :) @Barmar

Comment: yes on click on 1st image the first option from select field should be active , this is what i achieved already , it is getting active but it is not triggering the onchange event @Barmar